Фильтрация сообщений в чате Телеграмм
У меня есть задача создать бота, который будет фильтровать сообщения в чате и выполнять определенные действия. Ситуация такая: есть канал и привязанный к нему чат для комментариев. Когда в канале появляется новый пост, пользователи оставляют к нему комментарии в чате. Но в этом же чате люди могут общаться на другие темы, и такие сообщения не являются комментариями к посту. Можно ли как-то отслеживать только комментарии к постам, игнорируя обычное общение?
